# Troubles making a user update view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a custom user model, subclass of `AbstractBaseUser`.
I'm currently having troubles making an update view, so user could change his profile. Changing user through admin interface works fine.

This is a form that I use to change user objects in both admin and app`s interface.

```
class UserChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField(
        label=_("Password"),
        help_text=_(
            "Raw passwords are not stored, so there is no way to see this "
            "user's password, but you can change the password using "
            "<a href=\"{}\">this form</a>."
        ),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        password = self.fields.get('password')

        if password:
            password.help_text = password.help_text.format('../password/')
        user_permissions = self.fields.get('user_permissions')
        if user_permissions:
            user_permissions.queryset = user_permissions.queryset.select_related('content_type')

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]
```

I'm using `fields = '__all__'` to be able to change all the fields through admin interface. But in app's intreface I want user to change only some fields.
This in my view:

```
def update_user(request):
    form = UserChangeForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user, fields=('email', 'first_name'))

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

        return render(request, 'update_user.html', {'form': form})

    return render(request, 'update_user.html', {'form': form})
```

If I pass `fields` parameter like that `UserChangeForm(request.POST or None, request.user, fields=('email', 'first_name'))` I get `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fields'` error.

If I don't pass it I get exacty same form with all the fileds as in the admin inface.

How can I get this form show only fields I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to create a subclass of the `UserChangeForm` so that you can choose fields you want in the `Meta` class:

```
class MyUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta(UserChangeForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'first_name]
```

And then in your view you use the new form you made:

```
def update_user(request):
    form = MyUserChangeForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
    # and so on ...
```